# Set an imageview instance by another one

Tags: android, imageview

Here is my code :

```
   ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
   ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
```

I would like to know if it's possible to set the R.id.image1 to the same as R.id.image2 dynamically.

R.id.image1 contains no image but if R.id.image2 got an image I would like that R.id.image1 display the same image as R.id.image2

Comment: Just make the same `setImage*()` call on both `ImageView`s. What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: `iv1.setImageDrawable(iv2.getDrawable());` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything under `R` is defined at compile time based off of your resources. (Layouts, images, dimens, etc.) That means that you can't change what `R.id.image1` means at runtime but you can have multiple `ImageView`s point to the same resource:

```
ImageView image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
ImageView image1Dup = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
```

Alternatively you can set the image from one `ImageView` to another one.

```
image1.setImageDrawable(image2.getDrawable());
```